# Is it possible to save every webpage you visit?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, webpage

Is it possible to save everypage you visit in a browser automatically? I do now want to rely on Cache as a huge cache will slow down the browser. A third party software or an add-on will be helpful.

I use Chrome browser, but any other browser which can help me in my requirement is okay.

Comment: Save it for what?  Do you actually plan to use the saved pages as an alternative cache or just keep a long history?

Comment: I basically work offline some times, and I want to be able to view the saved version of a webpage.

Comment: Is switching browsers an option?  Firefox has an offline mode you can manually enable.

Comment: Do you want to save just the viewed pages or the whole tree? How many levels deep do you want to save?

Comment: My approach would be to use some sort of caching proxy that achieves this functionality. Sadly, I know of none that do precisely this and there are limitations (mostly due to HTTPS.)

Comment: `Is it possible to save everypage you visit in a browser automatically? I basically work offline some times, and I want to be able to view the saved version of a webpage. I do now want to rely on Cache.`   But you just described a cache. If you download it, then it will be cached. If you downloade everything, then it will be huge. So you want a cache but by a different name? ಠ_ఠ How about simply calling the cache a *document store*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Firefox, there is [Auto Save Document](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2704/) addon which can store the currently shown document in a separate directory automatically when browsing a certain site. Unfortunately, it has some limitations. The documents are stored as html-text only (no embedded objects like pictures etc.), and there's 100 pages limit. So I'm not sure if it can meet your needs.

Another Firefox addon is [Read It Later](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7661/). It can save pages to a reading list with just one click. It's not full automatic, so you need to click on the small arrow next to the location bar whenever you want to save a page.

Comment: Auto Save Document sounds interesting. Is there such an addon for Chrome?

Comment: @Ctroy: As I don't use Chrome, I don't have any idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the author of SingleFile. This Web Extension has been rewritten to be compatible with Chrome and Firefox (desktop and mobile). It has an "Auto-save" mode than allows you to save all the pages you visit in the current tab, or all the unpinned tabs, or all the tabs.

You can find more info and download links on the GitHub page: https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile.

Comment: Is it possible to override the defaults using terminal or bash script? I need to enable the "auto save all tabs" mode by default and disable screen overlay while downloading.

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question then, I think the need here is an extension that would save every page's text/low-rez images to have a sort of wayback machine that would save everything (to less than 500ko per site for example) that wouldn't make lag usual naviguation.

Answer (score 3):

It is decently involved, as it means setting up some kind of local server, but [this](http://craiget.com/2011/10/automatically-save-html-of-every-page-you-visit/) page describes, and has the code to create an extension that will do what you want exactly.

You will need a web server that can support PHP ([XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) or other), and chrome, and it will probably take a little fiddling, but with some work, does what you want, and is very customizable.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. After some tinkering with the script and the PHP side, it does what I want. Thanks!

Comment: https://craiget.com/javascript/automatically-save-html-of-every-page-you-visit   Web pages has been re-designed here's the new link.

Comment: (yet another) Updated link: https://craiget.com/automatically-save-html-of-every-page-you-visit.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use website grabber softwares or browser add-ons.
Unless you want this to happen by default for every site you visit.

Comment: I want to save every webpage I visit, not manually, but automatically. I know it's kinda crazy, but I need it. :)

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome, you might be able to use the extension [Read Later Fast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/decdfngdidijkdjgbknlnepdljfaepji), which adds "Read Later" in the right-click menu to save page or link to the RLF app, then find RLF as a new tab of the browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have not used it, but I saw this today https://www.hunch.ly/

From the site:

> Your Research Sidekick
>
> Inspector Hunchly toils in the background of your web browser to track, analyze and store web pages while you perform online investigations. Forgets nothing, keeps everything.

Edit:
Also found:

- [Evernote Web Clipper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/evernote-web-clipper/pioclpoplcdbaefihamjohnefbikjilc?hl=en)
- [Save to Google Drive](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-to-google-drive/gmbmikajjgmnabiglmofipeabaddhgne?hl=en)

Comment: Hunch.ly currently costs 100$ Canadian dollars https://www.hunch.ly/hunchlysignup/

Answer (score 0):

WARC writers

- https://github.com/internetarchive/warcprox

WARC readers

- https://github.com/Webrecorder/pywb

  - https://github.com/iipc/openwayback - deprecated in favor of pywb
- https://github.com/internetarchive/brozzler
- https://github.com/webrecorder/webrecorderplayer-electron

content extractors

- https://github.com/gwu-libraries/sfm-ui - Flickr, Twitter, Sina Weibo, Tumblr

  - partially based on warcprox https://github.com/gwu-libraries/sfm-utils/blob/master/sfmutils/warcprox.py

other tools

- http://proxy-offline-browser.com/ - freeware/commercial. By passing all your web traffic through WebAssistant, you instantly and transparently build a copy of all the pages you visit - so they're yours to surf offline whenever you like. When online the proxy updates your cached web pages and adds new pages automatically.

old

- http://www.gedanken.org.uk/software/wwwoffle/ - caching http proxy server, World Wide Web Offline Explorer. last release: 2016
- https://github.com/idibidiart/AllSeeingEye - Google Chrome Extension. Record All Browsing in Screenshots & Full Text. last commit: 2014

see also

- https://github.com/iipc/awesome-web-archiving
- https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/82ir3k/automatically_archiving_all_visited_web_pages/

Answer (score -1):

You could print, safe as pdf, or use a browser add on button to do the task. Build an old school file system and keep track of it.