# How to make Chrome save websites for offline use automatically

Tags: google-chrome

I was using Chrome when the power went off and the internet was cut for about 10 mins. So I was wondering if there was an app that automatically saved the websites I visited in Chrome, and made them available for offline use. May be an extension or procedure?

Comment: Complete websites, or webpages only?

Comment: Just whatever I view.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go:**

- [Is it possible to save every webpage you visit?](https://superuser.com/questions/240458/is-it-possible-to-save-every-webpage-you-visit)
- [Scrapbook for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/scrapbook/)
- [Scrapbook Chromium](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromium-scrapbook/gokffdfnlmampchciemmflgbckijpmlb)
- [Scrapbook for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scrapbook/fihabipakbgncingdhhdidlbhneeicne)
- [Pocket](http://getpocket.com/) - Requires signup

Comment: It should automatically save all the pages I visit, I dont see an option for that...

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice that but check this page: http://superuser.com/questions/240458/is-it-possible-to-save-every-webpage-you-visit

Answer (score 0):

When you find something
you want to view later,
put it in [Pocket](http://getpocket.com/).
pocket is my personal favorite.but you can also try [Readability](http://www.readability.com/) & [Instapaper](http://www.instapaper.com/)

you will know merits and demerits of each via this [link](http://lifehacker.com/5894995/bookmark-and-read-later-apps-compared-read-it-later-vs-instapaper-vs-readability)

Comment: Curious that pretty much all *save-to-read-offline-without-a-connection* programs require signing up and creating an account on their websites for them to work. ಠ_ಠ